# Is it possible to differentiate between character and integer stored in the same integer array?

Tags: java

My code is

```
int array[] = {'a',98};
for(int num:array) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

If I print this, I'll get o/p as **97 98**.

If I print `(char) num` then o/p will be **a b**.

Is it possible to print the array as **a 98**? My guess is as array will store integer values of the array elements, it is not possible. But any solution here?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this.
What's the reason you want to do this? Maybe you should use a different approach?

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Can you use `List` instead?

Comment: Once the values are in the array, they are plain integers.There is no way to know wether they came from a character or a regular integer.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm I was curious about it

Comment: Not possible for primitives, you could use wrapper for these to distinguish. Regards...

Comment: Well not with integer type but It should (I'm not from java) be possible with custom coded class, shouldn't it?

Comment: While the `Object array[]` approaches in the provided answers are correct, you should avoid mixing data types in this fashion. If you must, wrap primitives in your own abstract data type or keep them separate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do it with `int[]`. But you can create `Object[]` to achieve this.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object array[] = {'a',98};
    for(Object o : array){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a
98
```

Comment: If there is only two possible types (char and int), I'd rather create a custom object which keep holds of the value and make sure it is either an int or a char. That way you avoid dangerous behavior, as the Object array could be filled with anything.

Answer (score 11):

You have `int[] array`, that's how the bytecode looks:

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1    // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2
       1: newarray       int
       3: dup
       4: iconst_0
       5: bipush        97
       7: iastore
       8: dup
       9: iconst_1
      10: bipush        98
      12: iastore
      13: astore_1
      14: return
}
```

As you can see, values are inserted as `int`.

Other users suggested using `Object[] array`. Look at the bytecode of it:

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1       // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2
       1: anewarray     #2      // class java/lang/Object
       4: dup
       5: iconst_0
       6: bipush        97
       8: invokestatic  #3      // Method java/lang/Character.valueOf:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
      11: aastore
      12: dup
      13: iconst_1
      14: bipush        98
      16: invokestatic  #4      // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      19: aastore
      20: astore_1
      21: return
}
```

Note the

```
// Method java/lang/Character.valueOf:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
```

line, which tells that the method `Character.valueOf` is invoked, so you'll get the actual character instead of its `int` value.

Comment: pretty deep explaination. That means corresponding valueOf() method will be called to print it for the Object array which does not happen with arrays of primitive data types. Is it?

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible for an `int[]` to know if its data was written as a character or as a number in the source code. You need a different data structure if you wish to keep that kind of information.

Answer (score 9):

```
Object[] array = { 'a', 98 }
if (array[i] instanceof Character) { // Or Integer
```

Comment: If you use an Object-Array, he doesn't have to check the class, since the object's toString-method is called automatically. (In his printing-example)

Comment: Why the if-statement? Just use `array[i].toString()`to get an agnostic string representation.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors you don't even have to call toString(), since it is called automatically!

Comment: @ThomasBöhm and others right so. However if in real life one wants to actually _use_ the stored value... And also the question was how to distinghuish values afterwards.